# How to implement a generic method in Java to mange properties of a class?

Tags: java, oop

I have a Container class with two sets: one of type `A` and the other one of type `B`. I want to have a single method in my class which can receive an argument of type `A` or `B` and add it to the corresponding set. 
btw, I'm not sure if the interface `Something` should be used. Note that I want to avoid checking the class type of the received parameter with `getClass()` or `instanceof` since I have lots of sets in my project.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

```
public class Container{

privte Set<A> a;
privte Set<B> b;

public Container(){
    a = new HashSet<>();
    b = new HashSet<>();
}

//getters and setters

//generic method
public void addAorB(Something instance){
    //add to the coresponding Set
}
}

public class A implements Something{

}

public class B implements Something{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the generic types are disjunct I would put all sets into a map, each set's type as key. To avoid duplicated code I also would create a method which creates the set and puts it into the map.

```
private final Map<Class<?>, Set<? extends Something>> sets = new HashMap<>();

public Container() {
    a = createAndPut(A.class);
    b = createAndPut(B.class);
}

private <T extends Something> Set<T> createAndPut(Class<T> type) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    sets.put(type, set);
    return set;
}
```

If you only need the set-instances to add the elements, you may discard them. You can add a null-check if there is no set registered for the given instance.

```
public void addAorB(Something instance){
        Set<? extends Something> set = sets.get(instance.getClass());
        if (set == null)
            set = createAndPut(instance.getClass());
        ((Set<Something>) set).add(instance);
}
```

Comment: was just going to suggest something similar!

Answer (score -1):

```
public void addAorB(Something instance){
    //add to the coresponding Set
   if instance instanceof A
      a.add(instance);
   else if instance instanceof B
      b.add(instance);    
   else
      throw new Exception("class not supported");

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you want to avoid using instanceof